# I'm getting a runtime error on judge for a correct output of the problem

Tags: c, for-loop, runtime-error

I was trying to submit a problem in an online judge which **gives 5 number** and wants me to **Determine if the inputed numbers are consecutive by increment of 1** I tested my code and it runs properly but seems to get a runtime error when submitting it to judge. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int a[5];
int m,i,k;

for (m=0; m<5; m++){
scanf("%d", &a[m]);
}

int b[5];
int c[5];
for (i=0; i<5; i++){
  for (k=0; k<5; k++){
    if (a[i] < a[k]){
    ++c[i];
    }
  }

}
int j, d[5];
int length = 4;

for (j = 0; j<5; j++){
  d[j] = length - c[j];

}
int e[5],l,p;


for(l=0; l<5; l++){
  e[d[l]] = a[l];
}



if (e[1] - e[0] == 1){
  if(e[2] - e[1] == 1){
    if(e[3] - e[2] == 1){
      if(e[4]- e[3] == 1){
        printf("a straight\n");
      }
      else printf("not a straight\n");
    }
    else printf("not a straight\n");
  }
  else printf("not a straight\n");
}
else printf("not a straight\n");

return 0;
}
```

I know it is very long and I've found a shorter code, but I'm curious to know why this code receive a runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue lies in these two lines:

```c
int b[5];
int c[5];
```

the arrays `b` and `c` aren't filled with `0`s by default (they are generally filled with quite random values), which leads to unintended behavior.

The `segfault` on occurs the line `e[d[l]] = a[l];` because you are indexing into `e` which has room for 5 `int`s with an index that can be much greater than `4` since `d`s values depend on `c`'s values which might be very big: `d[j] = length - c[j];`.

To fix the issue, you can change these two lines with:

```
int b[5] = {0};
int c[5] = {0};
```

because this initializes `a` and `b` with `0`s.

Comment: Oh I see, I believe I understand now. Thanks for the very clear explanation aside from the fix to the issue on my question!